# Why is Hibernate working in production but not during tests?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, junit

Here is my PersistanceConfiguration from my Spring Boot app.

```java
@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"org.persistence.repository"},
        transactionManagerRef = "jpaTransactionManager",
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManagerFactory")
@ComponentScan("org.persistence")
public class PersistenceConfiguration {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PersistenceConfiguration.class);

    @Autowired
    private ResourceLoader resourceLoader;

    @Autowired
    private AuditInterceptor auditInterceptor;

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    private HibernateProperties hibernateProperties;

    @Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation() {
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        final LocalSessionFactoryBean sf = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();

        sf.setDataSource(this.dataSource);
        sf.setMappingLocations(getMappingLocations());
        sf.setHibernateProperties(getHibernateProperties());
        sf.setEntityInterceptor(auditInterceptor);
        sf.setAnnotatedClasses(getAnnotedClass());
        return sf;
    }

    @Bean(name = "entityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean bean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        bean.setPackagesToScan("org.domain.entity");

        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter hjva = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        bean.setJpaVendorAdapter(hjva);

        bean.setLoadTimeWeaver(new InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver());

        bean.setDataSource(this.dataSource);

        bean.setJpaProperties(getHibernateProperties());

        return bean;
    }

    @Bean(name = "entityManager")
    public EntityManager entityManager(EntityManagerFactory myEntityManagerFactory) {
        return myEntityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
    }

    @Bean(name = "jpaTransactionManager")
    @Order(3)
    public PlatformTransactionManager jpaTransactionManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        JpaTransactionManager txManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        txManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
        return txManager;
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean
    @Order(2)
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(final SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        final HibernateTransactionManager htm = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        htm.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);
        return htm;
    }

    @Bean
    public Properties getHibernateProperties() {
        final Properties properties = new Properties();

        // SQL dialect
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", this.hibernateProperties.getDialect());

        // Second-level cache
        properties.put("hibernate.cache.region.factory_class", "org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory");
        properties.put("hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache", "true");
        properties.put("hibernate.cache.use_query_cache", "true");
        properties.put("hibernate.cache.ehcache.missing_cache_strategy", "create");
        properties.put("hibernate.cache.provider_class", "org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider");
        properties.put("net.sf.ehcache.configurationResourceName", "/ehcache.xml");

        // Echo all executed formated SQL to stdout - False en production
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", this.hibernateProperties.getShowSql());
        properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", this.hibernateProperties.getFormatSql());

        LOG.info("RepositoryConfiguration.HibernateProperties: {}", properties);

        return properties;
    }
```

It perfectly works when I launch my app, for context I need to have an Hibernate sessionManager for the legacy code, and a EntityManager to use JPARepository in my new code.

The problem comes when I try to launch my tests. If I use a JPARepository method like a simple findById, nothing is found, but when I use a criteria from sessionManager, it finds the correct data.

I think my EntityManager is not properly connected for my tests, but I don't really know where to look at, I don't have xml configuration, just this.

```java
/**
 * The Class IntegrationTestConfiguration.
 */
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("org.test")
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:/application.properties", ignoreResourceNotFound = true)
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:/conf/variables.properties", ignoreResourceNotFound = true)
public class IntegrationTestConfiguration {

    /** The data source. */
    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    /** The flyway properties. */
    @Autowired
    private FlywayProperties flywayProperties;

    /**
     * Sql data type factory.
     *
     * @return the postgresql data type factory
     */
    @Bean
    public PostgresqlDataTypeFactory sqlDataTypeFactory() {
        return new PostgresqlDataTypeFactory();
    }

    /**
     * Db unit database config.
     *
     * @return the database config bean
     */
    @Bean
    public DatabaseConfigBean dbUnitDatabaseConfig() {
        final DatabaseConfigBean dbConf = new DatabaseConfigBean();
        dbConf.setDatatypeFactory(sqlDataTypeFactory());
        return dbConf;
    }

    /**
     * Db unit database connection.
     *
     * @return the database data source connection factory bean
     */
    @Bean
    public DatabaseDataSourceConnectionFactoryBean dbUnitDatabaseConnection() {
        final DatabaseDataSourceConnectionFactoryBean dbDsConnection = new DatabaseDataSourceConnectionFactoryBean();
        dbDsConnection.setDataSource(dataSource);
        dbDsConnection.setDatabaseConfig(dbUnitDatabaseConfig());
        return dbDsConnection;
    }

    /**
     * Flyway.
     *
     * @return the flyway
     */
    @Bean
    public Flyway flyway() {
        final FluentConfiguration conf = Flyway.configure();
        conf.dataSource(dataSource);
        conf.schemas(flywayProperties.getSchemas());
        conf.baselineOnMigrate(flywayProperties.getBaselineOnMigrate());
        conf.baselineVersion(flywayProperties.getBaselineVersion());

        final Flyway flyway = new Flyway(conf);
        flyway.migrate();
        return flyway;
    }

    @Bean
    public JavaMailSender getJavaMailSender() {
        final JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
        final Properties props = mailSender.getJavaMailProperties();
        props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");

        return mailSender;
    }

}
```

And here is my problem, how can I plug my entityManager to the sessionManager or the database and have access to my data during my tests?

An example of a test with JUnit:

```java
@Test
@Transactional
@DatabaseSetup(value = {
        "/dataset/input/programme/referent.xml" })
public void testChargerUnReferent(){
    //GIVEN
    ReferentDTO referentDTO;

    //WHEN
    referentDTO = referentService.chargerReferent(11L);

    //THEN
    Assert.assertEquals(Long.valueOf(11), referentDTO.getId());
    Assert.assertEquals(EnumReferentielReferent.ADEME, referentDTO.getType());
    Assert.assertEquals("Ademe1", referentDTO.getLibelle());
}
```

Comment: Are you using Spring Boot?

Comment: Yes, spring boot 2.3.1.RELEASE and Springframework 5.4.18.Final

Comment: Are you using @SpringBootTest for your Test class? Seems like you're not starting your application context in Test

Comment: Why are you configureing so much things that are usually auto-configured?

Comment: Let me tell you a little secret... The [`SessionFactory`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/javadocs/org/hibernate/SessionFactory.html) is an `EntityManagerFactory`... So with trying to configure both you are actually making things a bit complex. So you can actually ditch the `LocalContainerEntityManager` and `HibernateTransactionManager` and it will work. Altough I haven't tested it, you might even use the standard auto configured JPA setup and be able to inject the `SessionFactory` as it exposes the actual Hibernate `SessionFactory`.

Comment: I tried @SpringBootTest in ma test class, with no effect.

My legacy code should not be touch or moved. I have this annoying annotation in the main `@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class})`, so i have to do nearly everything manually. 

And yes, i've read that `SessionManager` implements `EntityManager`, but every exemple with it that came from 2014 and with deprecated methods and Hibernate classes.

This works with a bit of luck and not really the best way to do the job.